# Tab dislocation for custom image expanding preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make expanding image preview similar to [this](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/) but as I move from left to right clicking on the circular div, the tab shifts down from the pointer. I don't understand why this is happening.

Please refer my fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/nayyarmannu/uomr11qh/3/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=uomr11qh).

Please help me with this. I am unable to figure out where I am going wrong.

And is there any way to change the pointer color dynamically based on the color of the circular div?

Thankyou.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mn").click(function() {
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("href"); //Find the target via the href
    if ($(activeTab).is(':visible')) {
      $(activeTab).slideUp();
      $(this).removeClass("active");
    } else {
      $(".mn").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
      $(this).addClass("active")
      $('.tab').hide();
      $(activeTab).fadeIn();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.full-width-div {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            left: 0;
        }

.mn.active:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  margin: 0 0 0 -12px;
  /*width: 0;*/
  /*height: 0;*/
  border-left: 12px solid transparent;
  border-right: 12px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 12px solid red;
}

.img-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.img-circle {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.ratio {
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.img-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.mn.active,
.mn:focus {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  outline: none
}

.tab {
  display: none;
  clear: both;
  margin: 12px 2% 10px 0;
  background: red;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.col-custom-eight {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 12.5%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="full-width-div container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="wrap">
          <div class="row">
    
            <div class="col-custom-eight col-sm-2">
              <a href="#tab1" class="mn">
                <div class="ratio img-responsive img-circle" style="background-image: url(/img/analytics.png); background-color: #00BCD4;"></div>
                <div class="text-center caption">1</div>
              </a>
    
            </div>
    
    
            <div class="col-custom-eight col-sm-2">
              <a href="#tab2" class="mn">
                <div class="ratio img-responsive img-circle" style="background-image: url(/img/analytics.png); background-color: #FFC107;"></div>
                <div class="text-center caption">2</div>
              </a>
    
            </div>
    
    
            <div class="col-custom-eight col-sm-2">
              <a href="#tab3" class="mn">
                <div class="ratio img-responsive img-circle" style="background-image: url(/img/analytics.png); background-color: #795548;"></div>
                <div class="text-center caption">3</div>
              </a>
    
            </div>
    
    
            <div class="col-custom-eight col-sm-2">
              <a href="#tab4" class="mn">
                <div class="ratio img-responsive img-circle" style="background-image: url(/img/analytics.png); background-color: #FF9800;"></div>
                <div class="text-center caption">4</div>
              </a>
    
            </div>
    
    
            <div class="col-custom-eight col-sm-2">
              <a href="#tab5" class="mn">
                <div class="ratio img-responsive img-circle" style="background-image: url(/img/analytics.png); background-color: #00BCD4;"></div>
                <div class="text-center caption">5</div>
              </a>
    
            </div>
    
    
            <div class="col-custom-eight col-sm-2">
              <a href="#tab6" class="mn">
                <div class="ratio img-responsive img-circle" style="background-image: url(/img/analytics.png); background-color: #8BC34A;"></div>
                <div class="text-center caption">6</div>
              </a>
    
            </div>
    
    
            <div class="col-custom-eight col-sm-2">
              <a href="#tab7" class="mn">
                <div class="ratio img-responsive img-circle" style="background-image: url(/img/analytics.png); background-color: #00BCD4;"></div>
                <div class="text-center caption">7</div>
              </a>
    
            </div>
    
    
            <div class="col-custom-eight col-sm-2">
              <a href="#tab8" class="mn">
                <div class="ratio img-responsive img-circle" style="background-image: url(/img/analytics.png); background-color: #8BC34A;"></div>
                <div class="text-center caption">8</div>
              </a>
    
            </div>
    
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div id="tab1" class="tab" style="background-color: #00BCD4">Tab 1
                <div class="col-md-3"><img src="/img/analytics.png" class="img-responsive" /></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div id="tab2" class="tab" style="background-color: #FFC107">Tab 2
                <div class="col-md-3"><img src="/img/analytics.png" class="img-responsive" /></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div id="tab3" class="tab" style="background-color: #795548">Tab 3
                <div class="col-md-3"><img src="/img/analytics.png" class="img-responsive" /></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div id="tab4" class="tab" style="background-color: #FF9800">Tab 4
                <div class="col-md-3"><img src="/img/analytics.png" class="img-responsive" /></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div id="tab5" class="tab" style="background-color: #00BCD4">Tab 5
                <div class="col-md-3"><img src="/img/analytics.png" class="img-responsive" /></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div id="tab6" class="tab" style="background-color: #8BC34A">Tab 6
                <div class="col-md-3"><img src="/img/analytics.png" class="img-responsive" /></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div id="tab7" class="tab" style="background-color: #00BCD4">Tab 7
                <div class="col-md-3"><img src="/img/analytics.png" class="img-responsive" /></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div id="tab8" class="tab" style="background-color: #8BC34A">Tab 8
                <div class="col-md-3"><img src="/img/analytics.png" class="img-responsive" /></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rows have 1px height which results in the pointer dropping down 1px for every circle. I fixed your fiddle, see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/u8at0t6h/).

You can set the color of the pointer with just CSS, like for instance:

```
 a[href="#tab1"]:after {
  border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 188, 212) !important;
}

a[href="#tab8"]:after {
  border-bottom-color: #8BC34A !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dario for the answer. But this solution is not responsive. Try changing the size of the frame in fiddle and make it big. In full width window issue is the same.